# web Application in 1.1 is not runing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

We have a application in .net farmework 1.1 and i have made it build successfuly, now when tried to run this application i am getting the following error:

[image: Error]

I have googled and found some settings in IE, i have checked it in IE settings that windows authenticatiuon is enabled there. but i dont know why i am getting this, please help as i am totally new to VS 2003, We will convert this web application to 4.5 soon but before that we need to some specific task. please help me as soon as possible, thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your IIS settings?

Comment: Windows Authentication under Security (can't recall IIS 6.0 UI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error i remember was due to folder permission you need to give folder permission 
ie  by right clicking the folder and then selecting security tab and add aspnet or networkservice with full rights and second thing right click mycomputers and then select internet infromation services then right click your wibsite  and then select dotnet security click edit
in last check integrated windows authentication. Hope this helps let me know if you have any questions