# System.Security exception on asp.net webpage - c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I am having an issue where when I run my asp.net website, I get a security exception to do with the trust level in the config file. I have tried adding the following code into the config file in the solution, but no luck;

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

Description of the 'Security Exception' -

> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I am only trying to run this locally from Visual Studio, and it has been working before.

We have recently moved our environments from working in a TS session (where vs2010 is), to having our own virtual machines (where vs2012 is). To get to the VS2010, we have to remote in from our virtual machine, and each time we log in it brings over our documents folder and everything. Could it be to do with this, logging in from somewhere else causes permission issues?

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: you are having folder permission error  read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954995/web-application-in-1-1-is-not-runing/16955199#16955199 let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks, I think it may be to do with the fact that I am logging in via a temporary profile and the permissions may not be set correctly. I have raised it, so will see if that is the issue soon enough